# How to mock localforage.getItem() with Jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, ts-jest, localforage

I'm writing a test for code using [localforage](https://github.com/localForage/localForage), and I'm getting `undefined (reading 'getItem')` over and over again!

- `App.test.tsx`

```js
test('render App component', () => {
  jest.mock('localforage', () => ({
    getItem: (item: string) => {
      return { name: 'John' };
    },
  }));

  render(<App />);
});
```

but in vain...

```bash
  ● render App component

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getItem')

      124 |
      125 |   useEffect(() => {
    > 126 |     localforage.getItem('20220622').then((values) => console.table(values));
          |                 ^
      127 |   }, []);
      128 |
```

- `App.tsx`

```js
const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    localforage.getItem('20220622').then((values) => console.table(values));
  }, []);

  return (<p>Hello.</p>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mock this with creating a `localforage.ts` file in the root `__mocks__` folder. There you can mock any values or functions in this module and Jest will automatically use this.

```
// <rootDir>/__mocks__/localforage.ts

const mock = {
  setItem: async () => undefined,
  getItem: async () => undefined,
  removeItem: async () => undefined,
};

export default mock;
```

[Docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks)